# Swagger Codegen: Inheritance and Composition not working as expected

Tags: java, inheritance, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have the following short YAML:

```
# Transaction Request object with minimal information that we need
  Parent:
    required:
  - a
  - b
  - c
properties:
  a:
    type: number
    format: double
  b:
    type: string
  c:
    type: string

# Full transaction
Child:
required:
  - a 
  - b
  - c
allOf:
  - $ref: "#/definitions/Parent"
properties:    
  date: 
    type: string 
    format: date-time
  state: 
    type: string 
    enum: 
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
```

In Swagger UI and Editor these objects show up as I wish them to: `Child` inherits the `a`,`b` and `c` fields from `Parent` and has a few additional ones.

I would have expected:

```
public class Parent {

  private Double a;
  private String b;
  private String c;

  ...}
```

and

```
 public class Child extends Parent {

 // Superclass fields as well as:
 private Date date;
 private enum State {...};

  ...}
```

However, while the `Parent` class looked as expected, my `Child` class consisted of the following:

```
public class Child   {



@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) {
  return true;
}
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
  return false;
}
Child child = (Child) o;
return true;
}

... }
```

Which lacks even `extends`. When using a `discriminator` it works, but I don't really want Polymorphism - just plain inheritance. How can I accomplish this with Swagger Codegen?

---

Relevant `pom.xml` entry:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/test.yaml</inputSpec>
                    <language>jaxrs-resteasy</language>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/payment</output>

                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>src/java/main</sourceFolder>
                        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    </configOptions>

                    <groupId>net.product</groupId>
                    <artifactId>product_api</artifactId>
                    <modelPackage>net.product.product_api.model</modelPackage>
                    <invokerPackage>net.product.product_api</invokerPackage>
                    <apiPackage>net.product.product_api</apiPackage>
                </configuration>

                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-server-stubs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

Comment: Which version are you using? on 2.2.2-SNAPSHOT it works just fine for java using this yaml https://s3.amazonaws.com/genexuss3test/prueba.yaml

Comment: I was using 2.1.6, and then also tried using 2.2.1. I hadn't tried the latest dev build because we really wanted to use a stable version instead of a `SNAPSHOT` for building our stubs. Not only that, but maven also gives me an error when I try to enter `2.2.2-SNAPSHOT` as a version, saying that its POM is missing.

Comment: I just tried manually installing the `2.2.2-SNAPSHOT` jar into my local repository. Generating the stubs with that, however, yielded the exact same result as above. Could you tell me what language/framework you generated the stubs with? I'll update my post with my `pom.xml` entry in the meantime.

Comment: I checked with the versions you mentioned and with the one that's currently the master branch and I got your results. For some reason the one I  cloned from master 3 months ago works almost fine, [here is the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4p45mjTMTnLV0RNWXNBVFkzY00/view?usp=sharing). But there is an [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3544) on github that might be related to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cat:
  allOf:
  - $ref: "#/definitions/Animal"
  - type: "object"
    properties:
      declawed:
        type: "boolean"
Animal:
  type: "object"
  required:
  - "className"
  discriminator: "className"
  properties:
    className:
      type: "string"
    color:
      type: "string"
      default: "red"
```

You need add code at parent class

```
required:
    - "className"
```